# Pythonで書いたものをexe化したが，すぐに閉じてしまう．

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

Pythonで書いたコードをexe化しました. その際に使用したコマンドラインオプションは

```
pyinstaller test.py -F
```

(※一度 `-F` を付けずに作成しましたが，起動してタスクバーに棒が一瞬表示されすぐ消えました．)

exeファイルを起動すると入力待ちの状態になります．
↑キーまたは↓キーを押すと下のエラーがコマンドプロンプトに表示され，すぐに閉じてしまいます．

原因を教えていただけると幸いです．よろしくお願いいたします．

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.8.5)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Trackback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 456, in <module>
 File "test.py", line 331, in main
 File "test.py", line 272, in draw_text
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io_BytesIO
[28628] Failed to execute script test
```

**コード:**

```py
import pygame
import sys
import math
import random
from pygame.locals import *

BLACK  = (  0,   0,   0)
SILVER = (192, 208, 224)
RED    = (255,   0,   0)
CYAN   = (  0, 224, 255)


#SEを読み込む
se_barrage = None
se_damage = None
se_explosion = None
se_shot = None

stage_idx = 0

switch = False
idx = 0
tmr = 0
bomb_tmr = 0
score = 0
hisco = 10000
new_record = False
bg_y = 0
#自機の移動範囲，小さい時とフルスクリーンの時とでの変数[MINI*4, FULL*4],[上, 下, 左, 右]
WAKU = [65, 665, 80, 608]


ss_x = 344                     #自機のx座標
ss_y = 620                     #自機のy座標
ss_d = 0                     #自機の傾き(0:なし, 1:左, 2:右　)    
ss_shield = 5                #残機
ss_muteki = 0                #無敵判定用
key_spc = 0
key_z = 0
key_x = 0
key_shift = 0
MISSILE_MAX = 200            #自機の弾の最大数
msl_no = 0                   #弾の発射に使う変数
speed_mod = False            #自機の移動速度遅くする変数(True:遅い, False:速い)
speed_jiki = 10              #自機の移動距離の変数

msl_f = [False]*MISSILE_MAX  #弾の存在を確認する変数
msl_x = [0]*MISSILE_MAX      #弾のx座標
msl_y = [0]*MISSILE_MAX      #弾のy座標
msl_a = [0]*MISSILE_MAX      #弾の角度
msl_type = [0]*MISSILE_MAX     #弾の種類
kakudo = 0 #弾の角度
BOMB = 3
graze = 0

ENEMY_MAX = 200             #敵の最大数
emy_no = 0                   #敵を出すときに使うリストの添え字用の変数
emy_f = [False]*ENEMY_MAX    #敵が出現しているか管理するフラグのリスト
emy_x = [0]*ENEMY_MAX        #敵のx座標
emy_y = [0]*ENEMY_MAX        #敵のy座標
emy_a = [0]*ENEMY_MAX        #敵の角度
emy_type = [0]*ENEMY_MAX     #敵の種類
emy_speed = [0]*ENEMY_MAX    #敵の速さ
emy_shield = [0]*ENEMY_MAX   #敵の体力
emy_decay = [0]*ENEMY_MAX     #敵の弾の種類
emy_count = [0]*ENEMY_MAX    #敵の動きを管理するリスト

LINE_T = 0                 #敵が消える上ラインの座標
LINE_B = 702                 #敵が消える下ラインの座標
LINE_L = 22                 #敵が消える左ラインの座標
LINE_R = 630                #敵が消える右ラインの座標

EFFECT_MAX = 150             #爆発の最大数
eff_no = 0                   #爆発を使う変数
eff_p = [0]*EFFECT_MAX       #爆発の画像番号用のリスト
eff_x = [0]*EFFECT_MAX       #爆発のx座標
eff_y = [0]*EFFECT_MAX       #爆発のy座標

eff_nog = 0                   #爆発を使う変数
eff_pg = [0]*EFFECT_MAX       #爆発の画像番号用のリスト
eff_xg = [0]*EFFECT_MAX       #爆発のx座標
eff_yg = [0]*EFFECT_MAX       #爆発のy座標
key_if = False

shot_ang=0
rooper = 0

bar_x = 160
bar_y = 280

tamadashi = True


def get_dis(x1, y1, x2, y2): #二点間の距離を求める関数

    return( (x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2) )

def move_starship(scrn, key): #自機の操作に関する関数
    global idx, tmr, ss_x, ss_y, ss_d, key_spc, key_z, key_x, key_shift, ss_shield, ss_muteki, speed_mod, speed_jiki, mini_big, BOMB, bomb_tmr, graze, score
    ss_d = 0 #傾きを０（なし）にする

    if speed_mod == True:
        speed_jiki = 4
    else:
        speed_jiki = 15

    if key[pygame.K_UP] == 1: #上操作
        ss_y = ss_y - speed_jiki
        if ss_y < WAKU[0]:
            ss_y = WAKU[0]
    if key[pygame.K_DOWN] == 1: #下操作
        ss_y = ss_y + speed_jiki
        if ss_y > WAKU[1]:
            ss_y = WAKU[1]
    if key[pygame.K_LEFT] == 1: #左操作
        ss_d = 1 #傾きを１（左）にする
        ss_x = ss_x - speed_jiki
        if ss_x < WAKU[2]:
            ss_x = WAKU[2]
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT] == 1: #右操作
        ss_d = 2 #傾きを２（右）にする
        ss_x = ss_x + speed_jiki
        if ss_x > WAKU[3]:
            ss_x = WAKU[3]

    key_z = (key_z+1)*key[K_z]   #Zキーで通常ショット
    if key_z%4 == 1:
        set_missile(0)

    key_x = (key_x+1)*key[K_x]   #Xキーでボム
    if key_x == 1 and BOMB > 0 and bomb_tmr == 0:
        set_missile(10)
        BOMB = BOMB - 1

    if key[pygame.K_LSHIFT] == 1: #Shiftで低速
        speed_mod = True
    else:
        speed_mod = False

    if bomb_tmr > 0:
        bomb_tmr = bomb_tmr - 1

    if ss_muteki > 0:
        ss_muteki = ss_muteki - 1
        return
    elif idx == 1:
        for i in range(ENEMY_MAX):
            if (emy_f[i] ==True) and (emy_type[i] != 17) and (emy_type[i] != 18):
                w = 100
                h = 100
                r = int ((w+h)/4 + (18+18)/4)
                if get_dis(emy_x[i], emy_y[i], ss_x-10, ss_y-8) < r*r:
                    ss_shield = ss_shield - 1
                    BOMB = 3
                        
                    if ss_muteki == 0:
                        ss_muteki = 180
                    if ss_shield <= 0:
                        ss_shield = 0
                        idx = 2
                        tmr = 0
                    if emy_type[i] != 13:
                        emy_f[i] = False #自機の操作に関する関数

    for i in range(ENEMY_MAX):
            if (emy_f[i] ==True) and (emy_type[i] != 17) and (emy_type[i] != 18) and (emy_type[i] != 0) and (emy_type[i] != 13) and (emy_type[i] != 14):
                w = 100
                h = 100
                r = int ((w+h)/4 + (18+18)/4)
                if get_dis(emy_x[i], emy_y[i], ss_x-14, ss_y-8) < r*r+1000:
                    graze = graze + 1
                    score = score + 10


def set_missile(typ):
    global msl_no, ss_muteki, bomb_tmr
    if typ == 0:
        msl_f[msl_no] = True
        msl_x[msl_no] = ss_x-8
        msl_y[msl_no] = ss_y-50
        msl_a[msl_no] = 270
        msl_type[msl_no] = 1
        msl_no = (msl_no+1)%MISSILE_MAX
    if typ == 10:
        msl_f[msl_no] = True
        msl_x[msl_no] = ss_x
        msl_y[msl_no] = ss_y-50
        msl_a[msl_no] = 270
        msl_type[msl_no] = 2
        ss_muteki = 240
        bomb_tmr = 180
        msl_no = (msl_no+1)%MISSILE_MAX#自機の弾をセット

def move_missile(scrn):
    for i in range(MISSILE_MAX):
        if msl_f[i] == True:
            if msl_type[i] == 1:#通常弾
                msl_x[i] = msl_x[i] + 36*math.cos(math.radians(msl_a[i]))
                msl_y[i] = msl_y[i] + 36*math.sin(math.radians(msl_a[i]))

            elif msl_type[i] == 2:#ボム
                msl_x[i] = msl_x[i] + 36*math.cos(math.radians(msl_a[i]))
                msl_y[i] = msl_y[i] + 3*math.sin(math.radians(msl_a[i]))

            if msl_type[i] == 1:
                if msl_y[i] < 0 or msl_x[i] < 0 or msl_x[i] > 960:
                    msl_f[i] = False#弾の移動

            elif msl_type[i] == 2:
                if msl_y[i] < -300 or msl_x[i] < -300 or msl_x[i] > 960:
                    msl_f[i] = False#弾の移動

def bring_enemy():#敵を出すシナリオ
    global ss_x, ss_y, kakudo, stage_idx, idx
    sec = tmr/30
    if sec%1 == 0:
        set_enemy(334, LINE_T, 90, 0, 3, 3, 0)


def set_enemy(x, y, a, ty, sp, sh, dec):
    global emy_no
    while True:
        if emy_f[emy_no] == False:
            emy_f[emy_no] = True
            emy_x[emy_no] = x         #敵のX
            emy_y[emy_no] = y         #敵のY
            emy_a[emy_no] = a         #敵の角度
            emy_type[emy_no] = ty     #敵のtype
            emy_speed[emy_no] = sp    #敵のspeed
            emy_shield[emy_no] = sh   #敵の体力
            emy_decay[emy_no] = dec
            emy_count[emy_no] = 0
            break
        emy_no = (emy_no+1)%ENEMY_MAX#敵機のセット

def move_enemy(scrn):#敵機の移動
    global tmr, shot_ang, sec, idx, score, ss_shield, hisco, new_record, stage_idx, tamadashi, ss_x, ss_y, BOMB, switch
    for i in range(ENEMY_MAX):
        if emy_f[i] == True:

            if emy_type[i] == 0: #ヒットチェック
                w = 100
                h = 100
                r = int((w+h)/4)+12
                er = int((w+h)/4)
                for n in range(MISSILE_MAX):
                    if msl_f[n] == True and get_dis(emy_x[i], emy_y[i], msl_x[n], msl_y[n]) < r*r:
                        msl_f[n] = False
                        if msl_type[i] == 1 and emy_count[i] != 2:
                            emy_shield[i] = emy_shield[i] - 1
                        if msl_type[i] == 2 and emy_count[i] != 2:
                            emy_shield[i] = emy_shield[i] - 10
                        score = score + 100
                        if score > hisco:
                            hisco = score
                            new_record = True
                        if emy_shield[i] == 0:
                            emy_f[i] = False

    for i in range(ENEMY_MAX):
        if emy_f[i] == True and tamadashi == True:
            if emy_x[i] < LINE_L or emy_x[i] > LINE_R or LINE_B < emy_y[i] or LINE_T > emy_y[i]:#敵が画面外に出たら消す
                emy_f[i] = False

def draw_text(scrn, txt, x, y, siz, col): #文字を表示する関数
    fnt = pygame.font.Font(None, siz)
    cr = int(col[0]/2)
    cg = int(col[0]/2)
    cb = int(col[0]/2)
    sur = fnt.render(txt, True, (cr, cg, cb))
    x = x - sur.get_width()/2
    y = y - sur.get_height()/2
    scrn.blit(sur, [x+1, y+1])
    cr = col[0]+128
    if cr > 255: cr = 255
    cg = col[1]+128
    if cg > 255: cg = 255
    cb= col[1]+128
    if cb > 255: cb = 255
    sur = fnt.render(txt, True, (cr, cg, cb))
    scrn.blit(sur, [x-1,y-1])
    sur = fnt.render(txt, True, col)
    scrn.blit(sur, [x,y])#文字を表示する関数

def main():
    global idx, bg_y, tmr, score, ss_x, ss_y, ss_d, ss_shield, ss_muteki, new_record, bar_x, bar_y, tamadashi, stage_idx, hisco, BOMB
    global se_barrage, se_damage, se_explosion, se_shot

    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption("東方薬生郷")
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((960, 720))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    up = 0
    down = 0
    zoom_s = 1.0
    zoom_q = 1.0

    tmr_keep = 0
    continue_nokori = 3
    warning_count = 0

    while True:
        if score > hisco:
                            hisco = score
                            new_record = True
        tmr = tmr + 1
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE and idx == 1:
                    idx = 4
                    tmr = 0

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if idx == 0:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        draw_text(screen, "START", 334, 300, 80, RED)
                        bar_y = 200

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        draw_text(screen, "QUIT", 334, 380, 80, RED)
                        bar_y = 450
                    
            if key[K_z] == 1 and bar_y == 200:
                idx = 1
                tmr = 0
                score = 0
                new_record = False
                ss_x = 334
                ss_y = 600
                ss_d = 0
                ss_shield = 5
                BOMB = 3
                ss_muteki = 0
                for i in range(ENEMY_MAX):
                    emy_f[i] = False
                for i in range(MISSILE_MAX):
                    msl_f[i] = False

            if key[K_z] == 1 and bar_y == 450:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()


        if idx == 1:#ゲームプレイ中
            tmr_keep = tmr
            move_starship(screen, key)
            move_missile(screen)
            bring_enemy()
            move_enemy(screen)
            draw_text(screen, str(score), 750, 190, 50, (255, 255, 255))
            draw_text(screen, str(hisco), 750, 100, 50, (255, 255, 255))

        if idx == 1.25:#ゲームプレイ中(BOSS 会話)
            tmr_keep = tmr
            draw_text(screen, str(score), 750, 190, 50, (255, 255, 255))
            draw_text(screen, str(hisco), 750, 100, 50, (255, 255, 255))

        if idx == 2:#ゲームオーバー
            move_missile(screen)
            move_enemy(screen)
            draw_text(screen, str(score), 750, 190, 50, (255, 255, 255))
            draw_text(screen, str(hisco), 750, 100, 50, (255, 255, 255))
            if tmr > 120:
                draw_text(screen, "GAME OVER", 334, 300, 80, RED)
                if new_record == True:
                    draw_text(screen, "NEW RECORD "+str(hisco), 334, 400, 60, CYAN)

            if tmr >= 300:
                draw_text(screen, "Press Z key to return to Title.", 334, 430, 60, SILVER)
                if continue_nokori != 0:
                    draw_text(screen, "Press C key to continue.", 334, 480, 60, SILVER)
                    draw_text(screen, "NOKORI"+str(continue_nokori)+"KAI", 334, 530, 60, SILVER)
                if key[K_z] == 1 and key[K_c] != 1:
                    idx = 0
                    tmr = 0
                    bar_y = 0

                if key[K_c] == 1 and key[K_z] != 1 and continue_nokori > 0:
                    ss_shield = 3
                    idx = 1
                    tmr = tmr_keep
                    continue_nokori = continue_nokori - 1
                    tamadashi = True
                    ss_muteki = 180
                    BOMB = 3
                    ss_x = 344                     #自機のx座標
                    ss_y = 620                     #自機のy座標

        if idx == 3:#ゲームクリア
           
            draw_text(screen, str(score), 750, 190, 50, (255, 255, 255))
            draw_text(screen, str(hisco), 750, 100, 50, (255, 255, 255))
            if tmr > 120:
                draw_text(screen, "GAME CLEAR", 334, 300, 80, SILVER)
                if new_record == True:
                    draw_text(screen, "NEW RECORD "+str(hisco), 334, 400, 60, CYAN)
                elif new_record == False:
                    draw_text(screen, "SCORE"+str(score), 334, 400, 60, (255, 255, 255))
            if tmr >= 300:
                draw_text(screen, "Press Z key to return to Title.", 334, 440, 60, SILVER)
                if key[K_z] == 1:
                    idx = 0
                    tmr = 0
                    bar_y = 0
                    stage_idx = 0

        if idx == 4:
            move_missile(screen)
            move_enemy(screen)
            draw_text(screen, str(score), 750, 190, 50, (255, 255, 255))
            draw_text(screen, str(hisco), 750, 100, 50, (255, 255, 255))
            if tmr >= 15:
                    draw_text(screen, "Press Z key to return to Title.", 334, 300, 60, SILVER)
                    draw_text(screen, "Press C key to continue.", 334, 365, 60, SILVER)
                    if key[K_z] == 1 and key[K_c] != 1:
                        idx = 0
                        stage_idx = 0
                        tmr = 0
                        tmr_keep = 0
                        bar_y = 0
                        score = 0

                    if key[K_c] == 1 and key[K_z] != 1:
                        idx = 1
                        tmr = tmr_keep

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)#フレームレート
        
        #メインループ

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: このヘルプ記事 [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) を参考に、他の人が問題を再現・調査出来るようなソースコードとテストデータをテキストで提示してみてください。exe化に使ったツールとそのスクリプトや構成ファイルも記述してください。割とあるのが、全部を1つのexeファイルにまとめると動かないというものです。試しに対象スクリプトだけexeにする設定にしてみてください。それから発生したエラー表示は省略せず、全文を過不足無くテキストで提示してください。

Comment: 無関係かもしれませんが、`test.py`というファイル名はやめた方が良いでしょう。[Pythonでtest.pyを作るな！](https://qiita.com/msmhrt/items/7e2a335a4c64bcc6e044) それからexeを作る際に指定したコマンドラインオプションや設定/構成スクリプト等があればそれも追記してください。

Comment: エラーそのものはメッセージにあるとおり、272行目の`fnt = pygame.font.Font(None, siz)`で最初のパラメータが`None`だからでしょう。[pygame.font.Font](http://westplain.sakuraweb.com/translate/pygame/Font.cgi#pygame.font.Font) `filename引数にNone値が設定された場合は、Pygameの既定フォントを読み込みます。`とあるので、そのフォントが含まれていないか、その情報がexeにすることで正しくなくなった(pathが変わった)とかでしょう。この2つの記事では、一応直っているらしいですが。[pygame.font.SysFont(None, 20) crashes pyinstaller generated .exe #206](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/206), [Fix pyinstaller issues with pygame.font.Font #2133](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/2133)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

272行目の記述を以下の通り変更したところ，無事に動作しました．

**修正前:**

```
fnt = pygame.font.Font(None, siz)
```

**修正後:**

```
fnt = pygame.font.Sysfont("Arial", siz)
```